# Graphing for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm building a Xamarin Forms project for a client and we need a **graphing library** that will handle data live streamed as a **line chart that connects points**. I'm relatively new to the Xamarin community and was wondering if one of the more knowledgeable developers could point me toward a good library for this.

I saw Syncfusion Essential Studio but 2k a license is not in the budget and OxyPlot, but its website doesn't work (http://oxyplot.org/).

The first target platform is iOS.

Comment: Just use nuget for OxyPlot.

Comment: @Cheesebaron the oxyplot website doesn't work. Is there a better place to get info?

Comment: Their Github repository page is good.

Comment: @Cheesebaron it just links to their website which doesn't work.

Comment: >"OxyPlot, but it hasn't been updated in 440 days" It's not true. Last published: [2016-02-07](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms/1.0.0-unstable1983).

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin https://components.xamarin.com/view/oxyplot 441 days

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin ahh i see their nuget package was updated more recently: https://www.nuget.org/packages/OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`XLabs` has basic charting for iOS/Android/WinPhone:

- Charting : https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Charting

Personally the XLabs version was too simple for our needs, so we either:

1) Use native charting libraries via `Jar` and `sharpie` binding projects

- There are **lots** of options in the paid and OSS worlds for Android and iOS in this regard.

2) Use `NGraphics` to draw the graph using primitives within `Xamarin.Forms` apps

- https://github.com/praeclarum/NGraphics

Comment: Update on the readme file: "##NOTICE: This project is no longer maintained. It may not work with newer versions of Xamarin.Forms."   :-(

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [SciChart](http://www.scichart.com) for Xamarin - which provides rich, interactive high performance charts for iOS & Android.

Examples are hosted at Github: https://github.com/abtsoftware/scichart.xamarin.examples

A getting-started youtube video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYdab-0XHMA

[image]

*Disclosure: I am the tech lead on the SciChart xamarin project*

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for free controls you can use charting controls from Xamarin-Forms-Labs: [Xamarin-Forms-Labs Charting](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Charting)

[image]

You can also use [Telerik Charting Controls](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/xamarin-ui) which costs $799

Answer (score 2):

Syncfusion provides a [Free Community License](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense).

> The Community License provides free access to all the Syncfusion products for individual developers and small businesses.
>
> What's included?
>   All products available in Essential Studio Enterprise Edition and our enterprise solutions for big data, dashboards and reporting. Support and updates are also included.
>
> COMPONENTS AND FRAMEWORKS
>   More than 650 controls and frameworks for web, desktop and mobile development. The most comprehensive suite of components available for .NET, Javascript, iOS, Android and **Xamarin**, including grids, diagrams, schedules, gantt controls, maps, gauges, docking, ribbons and much more.

Xamarin charts are included as well.

Comment: I don't fall under the free license terms for this project.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going with Telerik's [UI for Xamarin](http://www.telerik.com/xamarin-ui) mainly due to business concerns. We have now switched to [SciCharts](https://www.scichart.com/examples/xamarin-chart/).

Another charting possibility I discovered is the [Xamarin.Forms Controls](http://www.infragistics.com/products/xamarin-forms) from Infragistics.